# Json: декодировать и распарсить

Tags: json, php

Получаю json вот в таком вот виде

```
[["","{\"completed_categorized_achievements\":{\"1\":{\"24\":[1389545685,1389545690,1389545696,1389546340,1389615978,1389691660,1389691863],\"10\":[1389544443,1389544447,1389544453,1389544471,1389544501,1389544559,1389544736,1389545035],\"12\":[1389541649,1389541649,1389541649,1389541649,1389541649,1389541649,1389541649,1389541658,1389545633,1389615332],\"22\":[1389438548,1389438559,1389438571,1389438623,1389541689,1389541788,1389541972,1389542271,1389542875],\"1\":[1389438628,1389541788,1389545685],\"7\":[1389438548,1389541690,1389541696,1389541732,1389541782,1389541845,1389688079,1389688402,1389689046],\"6\":[1393501256,1393501256,1393501256],\"9\":[1389438554,1389438563,1389438576,1389438628,1389542068,1389542129,1389542308,1389542613,1389543205],\"8\":[1389438551,1389541885,1389541891,1389541909,1389541941,1389542000]},\"3\":{}},\"division\":{\"v_div\":0,\"h_div\":0},\"static_resources\":{\"used_talents\":0,\"army_strength\":10,\"achievement_points\":640},\"wish_list\":{},\"global_collection_wish_item\":null,\"analytics\":null,\"talents\":{},\"expiring_resources\":{\"collection_receive\":{\"amount\":0,\"boost\":0,\"time\":0},\"global_collection_receive\":{\"amount\":0,\"boost\":0,\"time\":0}},\"names\":{\"squad_name\":\"\\u041c\\u043e\\u0439 \\u043e\\u0442\\u0440\\u044f\\u0434\"},\"static_maximum_resources\":{\"srup\":null,\"srua\":null,\"srut\":null},\"categorized_medal_slots\":{},\"current_territory\":\"0\",\"medal_slots\":{},\"chips\":{},\"uniform\":\"0\",\"territories\":{\"0\":{\"collected\":null,\"doll\":{\"0\":\"0\",\"1\":\"0\",\"3\":\"0\",\"4\":\"0\"}}},\"version\":65,\"last_login\":null,\"phrases\":{},\"experiences\":{\"experience\":610},\"completed_achievements\":{},\"decks\":{}}"]]
```

Нужно его как то декодировать и распарсить. Но блин. Как это сделать, если он уже декодирован

Comment: >Но блин. Как это сделать, если он уже декодирован

Как это он декодирован, если данные всё ещё находятся в JSON?

P.S.: у вас JSON не очень валидный, хотя может это так задумано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короч. Исправить пришлось вот таким глупым методом

```
$html = "json этот короч тут";
$search  = array('","{\"c', '}}}}"]]','\"');
$replace = array('",{\"c', '}}}}]]','"');
$html= str_replace($search, $replace, $html);
```

Comment: Ок, что дальше? Простите, но конкретнее вы можете поставить задачу, которую вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Уже решил. Я пытался сделать json таким что бы его можно было бы декодировать.